# storing map<string, struct> into vector to sort

Tags: sorting, dictionary, vector, struct

I have the following code that I am trying. I am trying to sort it by ascending or descending size, and from z-a (three different sorts). I can't figure out how to even store it in the vector let alone sort it. Thanks for the help!

```
  struct countSize {
        int count;
        uintmax_t size;

        void sortMap(map<string, countSize> &extCount)
    {
        // Copy 
        vector<string, countSize> v(extCount.begin(), extCount.end());

        // Sort the vector according to either file size or desc alphabetically


        //print

    }

int main()
{
map<string, countSize> mp;
 mp["hello"] = { 1, 200 };
 mp["Ace"] = { 5, 600 };
 mp["hi"] = { 3, 300 };
mp["br"] = { 2, 100 };

sortMap(mp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over a map, you get a stream of `std::pair<const X, Y>`. That's a bit awkward for storing in a vector, because of the `const`. One solution is to just drop the `const`:

```
using my_map = std::map<std::string, countSize>;
// Mutable element type.
using my_map_element = std::pair<typename my_map::key_type,
                                 typename my_map::mapped_type>;
using my_element_list = std::vector<my_map_element>;
```

Then it's very straight-forward to build a vector and sort it. Here, we use a template for the comparison function which makes it a lot easier to use a lambda for the comparator:

```
template<typename Functor>
my_element_list sortMap(const my_map& the_map, Functor compare) {
    my_element_list v(the_map.begin(), the_map.end());
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare);
    return v;
}
```

Unlike your code, this returns the sorted list. The caller can print the list if desired. See, for example, the example [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d926bc2118cae2cc).

That's not really ideal, though. If the individual elements of the map are at all complicated, it may well be more efficient to make a vector of *pointers* to the elements, rather than copies of the elements. Amongst other things, this does not require readjusting the element type, and that makes it possible to be agnostic about the base container type as well. However, you need to remember that the comparison functor will now receive pointers to the elements to be compared. See [the modified example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf68090ffe2883d8)